# Joining multiple same select statements into one (JOIN or UNION)?

Tags: mysql, join

I have the 4 following identical selects that return the same column outputs with different results.

something like :

1) `select a, count(*) from table a;`

2) `select a, count(*) from table b;`

3) `select a, count(*) from table c;`

4) `select a, count(*) from table d;`

they all output something like :

```
=================
a     |count(*) (Table a)| 
=================
hi    | 2
hello | 3    
why   | 4

=================
a     |count(*) (Table b)| 
=================
hi    | 4
hello | 6
why   | 8
```

Similarly for table c and d .

I wanted to do a join on all 4 of these tables so that I can get a single table where the same columns are summed and grouped and shown as one, Something like this

```
=================
a     |count(*) (Table a & b union )| 
=================
hi    | 6
hello | 9
why   | 12
```

I have worked out a query that works well for two tables but further unions on table don't work out well :

`select a, sum(total) from (select a, count(*) from table a union all select a, count(*) from table b) as T group by a;`

This works well for two tables but not more than that what am I missing.

Comment: You can extend Union all for more than two tables.

Comment: Why is this tagged both mysql & sql-server?

Comment: That last statement cannot be able to work. Where does 'total' come from?

Comment: He is trying to sum the counts, but, yes,  as he has not aliased the count(*) as total, it would not work

Comment: sorry yes missed the alias. I also found out the solution to this, I was actually missing the aliases :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a,
   sum(total) from
    (select a, count(*) AS total from table a 
        union all 
    select a, count(*) AS total from table b
        union all
    select a, count(*) AS total from table c 
        union all 
    select a, count(*) AS total from table d 
        union all 
    )
    group by a
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to do your unions before you do your counts as below

```
select a, count(*) from
(
select a from table a 
union all 
select a from table b
union all 
select a from table c
union all 
select a from table d
) as T
group by a
```